# Why does iphone simulator in xcode 4.3.2 come up with a blank white screen?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I have a major problem. My app was working perfectly fine back in xcode 4.2 and in iOS 5.0. However, when I updated to xcode 4.3.2 and iOS 5.1, I ran into an issue.

When I try running my app now, ios simulator comes up with my splash screen and then a blank white screen with a status bar. I also get

> 2012-04-08 20:46:48.025 Birdflix[67666:fb03] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

in the log.

Please help, I really need to publish my app. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please set `self.window.rootViewController` in
the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method in AppDelegate.m.

Comment: How do you do that exactly? Sorry I'm a newbie at xcode programming.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I haven't Xcode4.3.2, not always say rightly.

xcode 4.2, don't use MainWindow.nib, so  you should specify self.window.rootViewController.

the rootViewController is the ViewController that AppDelegate's view controller in 
  previous version's MainWindow.nib.

Suppose the class is RootViewController, then

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
          didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions   
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] init]; 
    [self.window.makeKeyAndVisible];

     return YES:
}
```

Comment: I specified that, however my app still launches with a blank white screen. I really appreciate all you help. I also believe that xcode is not recognizing any errors as well.